# unable to set listview text

Tags: android, listview, text

I am using json parser to pass image url and description into my listview. now i managed to load the images but how do i change the text for my list view? currently it just shows item 0, item 1 and so on.. how do i pass the description into the lazyadapter?

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // CREATING JSON PARSER OBJECT
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray guide = null;
    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    String[] mImageIds;
    ArrayList<String> guideList =new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> descriptionList =new ArrayList<String>();

    // GUIDE URL
    private static String url_guide = "http://58.185.41.178/magazine_android/get_guide.txt";
    private static final String TAG_GUIDES = "guides";          //the parent node of my JSON
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";        
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";        


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     // LOADING Guide IN BACKGROUND THREAD
        new LoadGuide().execute();

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this,guideList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        list.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadGuide extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * getting All videos from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_guide, "GET", params);

            // CHECKING OF JSON RESPONSE
            Log.d("All guide: ", json.toString());

            try {
                guide = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GUIDES);
                for (int i = 0; i < guide.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = guide.getJSONObject(i);

                    //String title = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);

                    guideList.add(image);
                    descriptionList.add(description);
                    System.out.println(guideList);
                    }           


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            // UPDATING UI FROM BACKGROUND THREAD
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */ 
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });


        }

    }


    }
```

Image adapter:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> guideList) {
        activity = a;
        data=guideList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText("item "+position);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position), image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: In `onPostExceute` you don't need `runInUIThread` This method always run in UI Thread.

Comment: @Sunny ok thanks for telling me. noted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter, you are making the TextView say "item 1", "item 2" etc specifically. What you need to do is add in the Adapter constructor your descriptionList

```
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> guideList, ArrayList<String> descriptionList) {
```

and then do

```
text.setText(descriptionList.get(position));
```

Comment: Thank you. I have solved my issue but theres another one, when i do "descriptionList.add(description);" and when i try to system.out.println, it prints "[Download Magazine]" with the brackets and on my list view, it shows it with the brackets too. how do i remove them?

Answer (score 0):

When your activity calls adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), that forces a re-draw of every item in the list.  That will trigger a call into the getView() method your adapter.  So your logic belongs in the getView() method:

```
text.setText(descriptionList.get(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single Hashmap for guidelist and descriptionlist and then pass that to the lazyadapter constructor. use the description part of the hashmap in the getview() method to the set the text.

Answer (score 0):

@user1933630

```
 descriptionList.add(description.subString(1,description.length()-1);
```

Comment: This is to remove that [] from the description. i don't have 50 reps to comment over there. so a new answer.